# Enable scrolling in a region for nested scroll views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am working with nested scroll views as described here to create cross-directional scrolling.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html

Is it possible to define a region that the user can touch to scroll while still passing those touches to the nested scroll views?

Here is an example using the image from that documentation link.  I only want the red region for `UIScrollView A` to be scrollable while still passing touches to `UIScrollView B` if the user scrolled on the right side.

The problem here is if I block touches using a method like `-pointInside:withEvent:` then the nested scroll views won't get the touch.  I want the nested scroll views to accept scrolling in the entire view but the parent to only accept scrolling touches in part of it's view marked in red for this example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload method [hitTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:), in your parent view. This method should returns active scroll view.

And also you should write some custom code to manage touchable areas.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (result)
    {
        if ([self scrollChildWithPoint:point])
        {
            result = self.childScrollView;
        }
        else if([self scrollParentWithPoint:point])
        {
            result = self.parentScrollView;
        }
        else
        {
            result = nil;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work because the nested scroll views won't get the touches if you block them from the parent scroll view.

Comment: You right about "pointInside" method, but hitTest works correct. (I've created small application with 2 scrollViews)